# Nginx proxy requests to docker containing react build app are not redirected properly

Tags: reactjs, docker, http, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a nginx listening on 8080 that proxies traffic to "/app/" to a webserver inside a docker on the same machine at port 3000:3000. The docker contains an application that is run with "npm serve", serving a bundled create-react-app.
When I run the docker container and access the site directly from the machine's browser at `http://localhost:3000`, it works fine. But when I access the site over the nginx proxy via `http://localhost:8080/app/`, nginx does proxy me to the app's index.html site (which seems to just do a redirect to the static content), but I don't receive 304 redirects, just 200, resulting in just a blank page.

I attached the docker to terminal and this is what I see when I access it directly via  `http://localhost:3000`:
[image: docker output directly]

vs over nginx `http://localhost:8080/app/`:
[image: docker output over proxy]

This is my nginx config file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    server {
            listen 8080;
            location /app/ {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
            }
    }


    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
```

The web directory looks like this:

```
- /
  | index.html
  | static/
      | css/
       ----| main.b09482.aa.css
      | js/
       ----| main.01948243.js
  |
```

But over the proxy approach, only the css folder is loaded into the sources in the browser, not the js folder.

This is the index.html file: (note that I didn't change anything in here, it's just the result of the npm build command)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <meta
            name="description"
            content="Web site created using create-react-app"
        />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
        <title>React App</title>
        <script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.6a029bf3.js"></script>
        <link href="/static/css/main.b09857aa.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript
            >You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript
        >
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```